# Regex to get words between ":" and "," in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning regex. I'm trying to get the most correct regex for the following :

Input is:

```
class:first,class:second,subject:math,subject:bio,room:nine
```

Expected output:

```
first,second,math,bio,nine
```

Want to store the above output in a string . var s = "";
Here's what I tried:

```
(:)(.*)(,)
```

However I want the last word too.

Comment: [`:([^,]+)`](http://regex101.com/r/aB5cP4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var re = /:(.*?)(?:,|$)/g; // `,|$` : match `,` or end of the string.
var str = 'class:first,class:second,subject:math,subject:bio,room:nine';
var result = [];
var match;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null)
    result.push(match[1]);
result.join(',') // => 'first,second,math,bio,nine'
```

Using [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var re = /:(.*?)(,|$)/g;
var str = 'class:first,class:second,subject:math,subject:bio,room:nine';
str.match(re).map(function(m) { return m.replace(/[:,]/g, ''); }).join(',')
// => 'first,second,math,bio,nine'
```

Comment: I want the last one two. With the above I don't get nine. & also I want to store it as a string. Not as an object. Maybe I can .stringify

Comment: @plalx, Thank you for comment. added `String.match` version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method (based on the request so far):

```
var str = 'class:first,class:second,subject:math,subject:bio,room:nine';

// global match doesn't have sub-patterns
// there isn't a look behind in JavaScript
var s = str.match(/:([^,]+)(?=,|$)/g);
// result: [":first", ":second", ":math", ":bio", ":nine"]

// convert to string and remove the :
s = s.join(',').replace(/:/g, '');
// result: first,second,math,bio,nine"
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQ5y7/)